# Is it possible to test CORS when running an API in-memory using WebApplicationFactory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cors, integration-testing

We have a test suite that uses `WebApplicationFactory` to run our Web API in memory. I've added CORS to the API via the usual .NET middleware and have verified it's working as expected using a `fetch` command in a browser console. I'd now like to have a test that ensures this CORS setup doesn't break in the future.

However, when I make a request to my API via the HTTP client of my in-memory server using the `OPTIONS` HTTP verb it always returns an HTTP 200 OK response. Even if I explicitly add an `Origin` HTTP header with an unsupported value.

Is there any way to test the CORS policy of an in-memory API like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it always succeeds"? You have to be more specific.

Comment: I mean the response is always an HTTP 200 OK. I'll update the question.

Comment: HTTP clients don't implement CORS. Browsers do. An HTTP Client doesn't have the concept of an Origin.

Comment: Well, I guess what I'm asking is whether it's possible to simulate a browser's implementation of CORS via an HTTP client.

Comment: @TomTroughton Simulating a browser's implementation of CORS via a HTTP client is possible, but I'm not aware of any such tool (other that perhaps https://www.test-cors.org/). An interesting idea, though. If I find some time, I'll produce a Go-based one.

Comment: Be aware that a `200` status is neither a necessary nor a sufficient condition for CORS to succeed. Your best bet, without using an existing tool, is to consult the de facto CORS spec: the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/).

Comment: You can, of course, implement tests that perform CORS preflight, etc., but I'd strongly urge you to reflect on what you're trying to prove with your tests. You're not a browser builder. You're not the author of CORS middleware. Those are both built and well tested. About the only rational thing to test yourself is that your policy is correctly defined and no automated test will do anything other than (in possibly odd ways) repeat the policy.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from @Damien_The_Unbeliever. But here I'm not using tests to verify browser behaviour or even the implementation of CORS middleware. Tests are self-documenting system requirements so what I want is a test that a) explains to a future developer that a specific CORS policy is expected on this API, and b) will fail if any future developer breaks this contractual commitment. Tests are our guarantee that an API meets its requirements, and a CORS requirement is a particularly elusive thing to verify via automation.

Comment: You *can* automate CORS tests, with unit tests that use Playwright or Selenium. Both Playwright and Selenium start up and control a browser, so you have a real CORS implementation. When you use HttpClient the only thing you can do is issue request (simple or preflighted) and verify their contents. That in itself is a *very* useful test that doesn't require emulating the browser. You can save successful responses (eg using Fiddler) and compare them with test responses. Playwright can record network traffic during a test so it can be compared against the expected traffic

Comment: Playwright also allows [testing APIs directly](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api-testing) by issuing API calls through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The OPTIONS verb returns the CORS policy, it doesn't check it. The browser checks the `Allowed-` headers in the response and decides whether to allow or reject a call. The best you can do with HttpClient is verify that the response is what was expected. In [MDN's CORS examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#examples_of_access_control_scenarios), the OPTIONS response is simple enough that it can be directly compared to a previous response once you remove the `Date:` header.

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2008 01:15:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

You can use tools like Fiddler or web test tools like Playwright and Selenium to record responses.

For realistic tests, you can use web test tools like Playwright or Selenium to make the API calls using an actual browser. Playwright also [allows testing APIs directly](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api-testing#complete-test-example) by issuing API calls through the browser.

From the Playwright docs :

```
[SetUp]
public async Task SetUpAPITesting()
{
    await CreateAPIRequestContext();
    await CreateTestRepository();
}

[Test]
public async Task ShouldCreateBugReport()
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data.Add("title", "[Bug] report 1");
    data.Add("body", "Bug description");
    var newIssue = await Request.PostAsync("/repos/" + USER + "/" + REPO + "/issues", new() { DataObject = data });
    Assert.True(newIssue.Ok);
}

private async Task CreateAPIRequestContext()
{
    var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    // We set this header per GitHub guidelines.
    headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    // Add authorization token to all requests.
    // Assuming personal access token available in the environment.
    headers.Add("Authorization", "token " + API_TOKEN);

    Request = await this.Playwright.APIRequest.NewContextAsync(new()
    {
        // All requests we send go to this API endpoint.
        BaseURL = "https://api.github.com",
        ExtraHTTPHeaders = headers,
    });
}
```

You can use this to test CORS by adding a custom `Origin` header or even loading a test HTML page before issuing the API calls.